# How to parse json with jquery and how to check it's valid json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm making an ajax call and receiving back what it supposedly json `resopnse`. I first need to know if this json is even well-formed, and if it is then how do I parse it with jquery? Here's what it looks like. They're only 2 records.

When I `alert(response);` I get

```
[object Object],[object Object]
```

and when I `console.debug(response);` I get the following 2 objects in this format

```
[Object { RowId=1,  more...}, Object { RowId=2,  more...}]
```

and when I click the `more` link for any of them, I get this

```
RowId         1
Description   "This is description of Row1"
Total         15
```

So does this look like well-formed json. Secondly, how do I parse it and use it in my jquery. I need a parsing way that's well supported. I tried `alert(JSON.parse(resp))` but it did absolutely nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's valid JSON, as it's not JSON at all any more. The jQuery Ajax call has already parsed the JSON into Javascript objets for you. The reason that you can't parse it is that it's parsed already.

If you want to parse the JSON yourself, you have to use the data type `text` so that you get the result unparsed.

Comment: It looks like you're right. I can access the fields with `response[0].RowId`. Is it usual for the ajax call to parse it automatically on its own without me asking for it? I just want to make sure this is going to be consistent behavior when I deploy and isn't just related to the browser or something.

Comment: @Gorge: Yes, when you specify `json` as data type, the result will be parsed automatically. The exact behaviour is specified in the documentation, under `dataType`: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 3):

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/
if it's an ajax request just do

```
$.ajax(/*url*/,
dataType: 'json',
success: function(data){
  //data is json and already evaluated!
});
```

Comment: +1. There's also $.post('/url/',{param1:value1,param2:value2},function(data) { /* success handler */}, 'json')

Comment: Well, actually, I'm the one generating the output on the server side too. This is why I'm asking if it looks like well formed json to make sure I'm doing it right on the server side. So I added `dataType: 'json'` to the .ajax call like you suggested and simply alerted the response and I still get `[object Object],[object Object]`. Does that mean that what I'm sending from the server isn't well-formed json?

Comment: @Gorge: The jQuery library manages to parse the JSON, but to tell if it's really well formed JSON you have to show what it looks like before it's parsed.

Comment: Use console.log instead of alert, you are using Firefox or Chrome right?  You will see data objects or you will json data objects in your error handler.  Either way, you should console.log to see what is returned.  If you are using Firebug and are sending valid response headers on the server side, Firebug will show the JSON return. jQuery does not require valid response headers.  If your server is publicly accessible, I can bounce requests off it and see if the return is valid.